Что им двигало, трудно сказать - знаки препинания
В предложении "Что им двигало, трудно сказать" перед словом "трудно" должна быть запятая или тире?

В зависимости от контекста возможны варианты.
Это СПП с придаточным изъяснительным в препозиции, когда возможна постановка запятой или тире (в зависимости от величины паузы).

Что им двигало, трУдно сказать.  Возможно для этого было причины.

Здесь после заданного предложения следует развитие темы, поэтому пауза небольшая, ставится запятая. Ударением выделена главная часть СПП.

Для такого поступка могли быть разные причины. Что Им двигало –  трудно сказать.

Здесь заданное предложение является заключительным, при этом придаточное выделено логическим ударением. Увеличенная пауза обозначена тире.
